# How to Hibernate Annotations with circular references

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables with circular reference

```
-----------------|                   |------------------
  product        |                   | product_detail
-----------------|                   |------------------
 product_id <pk> |                   | detail_id <pk>
  ...            | <-----------------| container_id <fk>
                 | <-----------------| product_id <fk>
                 |                   | ...
```

I want to know how to do the property annotations

> How to do **@OneToMany** annotation

```
Class Product
@OneToMany ???
public List<Detail> getDetails();
```

> How to do **@ManyToOne** annotations

```
Class Detail

@ManyToOne ???
public Product getContainer();

@ManyToOne ???
public Product getProduct();
```

I want to use the following code :

```
    Product p1 = new Product(name2);
    Product p2 = new Product(name1);

    Detail d = new Detail();

    d.setProduct(p2);

    p1.getDetails().add(d);

    ...

    Session.save(p1);
```

Then hibernate `insert into product` and `insert into detail` too.

I don't find the way to create the annotations to make it works. Can you help me, please?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_and_inverse_ManyToOne_annotations

Comment: mappedBy (on `@OneToMany`) makes it a BIDIRECTIONAL relation. That's all there is that is needed

Comment: Yes, it was the way i tried before post, but then i get an timeout exceeded error. @OneToMany(mappedBy="container") for getDetails() list and @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="container_id") for getContainer()

Answer (score 1):

In your situation your code should be as follows:

```
Class Product
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
public List<Detail> getDetails();
```

For the Detail class you should be able to use the @ManyToOne annotations as is. So:

```
Class Detail
@ManyToOne
public Product getContainer();

@ManyToOne
public Product getProduct();
```

The reasoning behind this is that in your @OneToMany you are noting in the mappedBy parameter which field in the Detail class is referring to **this Product**. You don't need any extra information in the @ManyToOne annotation as long as you stick to the standard naming conventions.

Comment: with this solution detail objet is not inserted in the db, only products

Comment: Hi axiorema, please take a look at https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/  and then check out the one-to-many section. Adding cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST to your @OneToMany annotation should take care of persisting the children along with your parent.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions posted using mappedBy but then when i run the example code only products are inserted on db.

The only way i found it works fine is using annotations with OneToMany side owner:

```
Class Detail
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="container_id")
    public Product getContainer() {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    public Product getProduct() {

Class Product
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="container_id")
    public Set<Detail> getDetails()
```

this is the example code:

```
    Product p1 = new Product("the container");
    Product p2 = new Product("the product");

    Detail d = new Detail();

    d.setProduct(p2);

    p1.getDetails().add(d);

    session.save(p2);
    session.save(p1);
```

in this case de two products are inserted and the detail is inserted too.

But there are an inconvenient, because if i don't want to receive a:

```
SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'container_id' cannot be null
```

i must to change de table detail and set up the foreign key 'container_id' to NULL, and this is not agree with the model

```
CHANGE COLUMN `container_id` `container_id` INT(11) NULL
```

where a detail must always have a container product.

Can anyone shed some light to the subject ?